# matplotlib import error in Mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

System: OX E
Python source: python.org

I used pip to install matplotlib and here is the result I got

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

> The directory '/Users/clarence/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent
>   directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been
>   disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
>   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory
>   '/Users/clarence/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not
>   owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check
>   the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
>   sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement already satisfied (use
>   --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5
>   in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): python-dateutil in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   pyparsing>=1.5.6 in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   backports-abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado->matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado->matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): six in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib) Clarences-MacBook-Pro:~
>   clarence$ sudo -H  pip install matplotlib Requirement already
>   satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5
>   in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): python-dateutil in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   pyparsing>=1.5.6 in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   backports-abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado->matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado->matplotlib) Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): six in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib)

When I go ahead the import that library in python. python says it could not find the modulus.

```
python3.5 -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__, matplotlib.__file__)'
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

How can I fix this?

Comment: All the `pip` messages concern python 2.7, you are using `python3.5`, you are running the wrong version of `pip` or `pip` in a 2.7 environment.  Install `matplotlib` in your 3.5 directory.

Comment: I have no idea how 3.5 was installed, and what your path names are.  Find the `pip` for 3.5 and run that by specifying the full hierarchic name.  If you don't know what that is then ask whoever installed 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install those libraries for the same version of python that you are using later to execute your code.

So if you want to use Python 2.7 you have to call

```
sudo pip2 install matplotlib
```

When using python 3.5 use it in a similar way

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```